# paging over all ingested docs in elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use primitive code like this:

```
var pageSize = 100;
var startPosition = 0;

do
{

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Bla>(s => s
        .Index(indexName)
        .Query(q => q.MatchAll()
        ).From(startPosition).Size(pageSize)
    );

    startPosition = startPosition + pageSize;

} while (true);
```

to page over all ingested documents. This breaks the server as the requests are too frequent I believe. I could slow things down by going to sleep for a few milliseconds, but I think this would still not be best practice.

I know there is also the concept of scrolling. How would I use this in my scenario, where I would like to act upon each page's result?

PS:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var indexName = "document";
    var client = GetClient(indexName);
    var pageSize = 1000;

    var numberOfSlices = 4;

    var scrollObserver = client.ScrollAll<Document>("1m", numberOfSlices, s => s
    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(numberOfSlices)
    .Search(search => search
        .Index(indexName).MatchAll()
        .Size(pageSize)
    )
    ).Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), r =>
    {
    // do something with documents from a given response.
    var documents = r.SearchResponse.Documents.ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(documents[0].Id);
    });
}
```

I am familiar with the observer pattern but not sure what exactly these components mean:

"1m"
numberOfSlices
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)

Comment: Did you tried elasticsearch scroll API? To retrieve large number of documents scroll API is recommended

Comment: I mentioned scroll but I would not know how to use it in my use cases - as i said

Answer (score 0):

Something along those lines seems to work:

```
const string indexName = "bla";
var client = GetClient(indexName);
const int scrollTimeout = 1000;

var initialResponse = client.Search<Document>
    (scr => scr.Index(indexName)
    .From(0)
    .Take(100)
    .MatchAll()
    .Scroll(scrollTimeout))
;

List<XYZ> results;
results = new List<XYZ>();

if (!initialResponse.IsValid || string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialResponse.ScrollId))
throw new Exception(initialResponse.ServerError.Error.Reason);

if (initialResponse.Documents.Any())
results.AddRange(initialResponse.Documents);

var scrollid = initialResponse.ScrollId;
bool isScrollSetHasData = true;
while (isScrollSetHasData)
{
    var loopingResponse = client.Scroll<XYZ>(scrollTimeout, scrollid);

    if (loopingResponse.IsValid)
    {
        results.AddRange(loopingResponse.Documents);
        scrollid = loopingResponse.ScrollId;
    }
    isScrollSetHasData = loopingResponse.Documents.Any();

    // do some amazing stuff
}

client.ClearScroll(new ClearScrollRequest(scrollid));
```